# Programmatic layout issue with incorrect height

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to create my own Toasts, and doing so by creating the layout programmatically and then setting the layout as the Toast's view to this layout.

This works absolutely fine for most of my code, but i've run into a quite specific issue i can't seem to fix.

I'm trying to add an image to the toast, and then display that image below or above the text.
This works 100% correctly when adding the image above the text. This is shown in the first image below:
http://i58.tinypic.com/zn2ag3.png

But when i try to add the image to the bottom, all hell breaks loose and i end up with this:
http://i59.tinypic.com/vdnyoj.png

Here's my code:

```
private void showToast() {
    //Variables
    Context context = getActivity();
    int imageGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    CharSequence text = "Test";

    //Create parent layout
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relLayoutParams);

    //Set background color
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);

    //Set padding
    int padding = 10;
    relativeLayout.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    //Initialize image
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int imageViewId = 0x100;
    imageView.setId(imageViewId);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_person_image);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int margin = 30;
    if(imageGravity == Gravity.TOP) {
        imageViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        imageViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        imageViewParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, margin);
    } else if(imageGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        imageViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        imageViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        imageViewParams.setMargins(0, margin, 0, 0);
    }

    relativeLayout.addView(imageView, imageViewParams);

    //Initialize textView
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    int textViewId = 0x101;
    textView.setId(textViewId);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if(imageGravity == Gravity.TOP) {
        textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageViewId);
    } else if(imageGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, imageViewId);
    }

    relativeLayout.addView(textView, textViewParams);

    //Setup the toast
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setView(relativeLayout);
    toast.show();
}
```

I'm hoping someone here can spot what is wrong with my code, as i've been unable to find the issue myself.

Comment: Why not use a `LinearLayout` with adding the child views in the required order?

Comment: Looks ok, except as @cketti has said `RelativeLayout` is unjustified in this simple case. The only thing I think about is your first `relLayoutParams`, which are applied to your top level `relativeLayout`. But this is not very correct, because, if I'm not wrong, the toast layout is attached directly to one of the high-level frame layouts, thus it should be framelayout params. Although, I doubt it is the real reason, but worth trying.